# Helm pass extra elements to an array

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

So I have an Helm template:

```
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: {{ .Values.dashboard.containers.name }}
          image: {{ .Values.dashboard.containers.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.dashboard.containers.image.tag }}
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          env:
            - name: BASE_PATH
              value: /myapp/web
```

and I want to pass extra environment variable to it

my `values.yaml`:

```
  extraEnvs:
    - name: SOMETHING_ELSE
      value: hello
    - name: SOMETHING_MORE
      value: world
```

how can I do it so that my result would be like this?

```
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: {{ .Values.dashboard.containers.name }}
          image: {{ .Values.dashboard.containers.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.dashboard.containers.image.tag }}
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          env:
            - name: BASE_PATH
              value: /myapp/web
            - name: SOMETHING_ELSE
              value: hello
            - name: SOMETHING_MORE
              value: world
```

I was thinking something like this:

```
  {{- if .Values.extraEnvs}}
    env: -|
    {{- range .Values.extraEnvs }}
      - {{ . | quote }}
    {{- end }}
  {{- end -}}
```

But this will override the previous settings

Comment: ever considered `toYaml` function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove the `env:` from your bit.

```
          env:
            - name: BASE_PATH
              value: /myapp/web
            {{- if .Values.extraEnvs}}
            {{- range .Values.extraEnvs }}
            - name: {{ .name }}
              value: {{ .value }}
            {{- end }}
            {{- end -}}
```

You can also use `toYaml` as mentioned in comments rather than iterating yourself.

Answer (score 4):

The `toYaml` way:

```
spec:
  containers:
    - name: {{ .Values.dashboard.containers.name }}
      image: {{ .Values.dashboard.containers.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.dashboard.containers.image.tag }}
      imagePullPolicy: Always
      env:
        - name: BASE_PATH
          value: /myapp/web
       {{- toYaml .Values.extraEnvs | nindent 10 }}
```

the nindent `10` is for normal deployment, and you may want to change to your own.